# C++ Locking window movement

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to lock my console window and prevent it from moving/being able to be moved.

Currently I have

```
::SetWindowPos(hConsole, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_DRAWFRAME | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

But "SWP_NOMOVE", I'm still able to move my console around and resize it.

```
::SetWindowPos(hConsole, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_DRAWFRAME | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

Comment: `SWP_NOMOVE` just tells `SetWindowPos` to ignore parameters regarding moving the window. You can modify the drag rectangle by listening to `WM_SIZING`. You can also hook the call to the window proc via a `SetWindowPos` by listening to `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` and then modify a struct to prevent moving.

Comment: Since you're doing this to a console window, I would hook the window procedure of the console window in order to intercept its messages.

Comment: The window sizing and positioning flags only work for the [SetWindowPos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos) call once, for example, If you have changed certain window data using [SetWindowLong](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlonga), you must call SetWindowPos for the changes to take effect. Use the following combination for *uFlags*: `SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED`. You can utilize Subclassing and change `WM_NCHITTEST` return value to prevent moving.